# Trigonometry and differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the expression $A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$ and I need to write it in the form $r\sin(wt−\theta)$.

I then have to determine $r$ and $\theta$ in terms of $A$ and $B$. If $R\cos(wt - \delta) = r\sin(wt - \theta)$, determine the relationship among $R, r, \theta,$ and $\delta$.

I think $R=r$, but I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the sine addition theorem:

$$r \sin{(\omega t-\theta)} = r \sin{\omega t} \, \cos{\theta} - r \cos{\omega t} \, \sin{\theta}$$

Comparing...we get

$$A = r \cos{\theta}$$
$$B = r \sin{\theta}$$

so that

$$r^2 = A^2+B^2$$
$$\theta = \arctan{\frac{B}{A}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that
$R = r$.
This is implied by the fact that
the extreme values of
$\sin$ and $\cos$
are $\pm 1$.

For your first expression,
expand
$r\sin(wt−\theta)$
using the formula for
$\sin(x+y)$,
equate the result to
$A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)$,
and see what you get
for $A$ and $B$
in terms of
$r$ and
$\theta$.